# JOGL Exception- Can't load library /natives/macosx-universal/gluegen-rt

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, opengl, apple-m1

I am trying to use openGL library using Intellij on Mac m1 and I used this tutorial https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_user_library

but I cannot run my class

`

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Chap2_App_1 implements GLEventListener {

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();


        gl.glColor3f(1f,1f,1f);
        //THE RECTANGLE
       

        gl.glColor3f(0f,1f,0f);

        //The triangle
        
        gl.glColor3f(0f,0f,1f);
        //The Line
        

        gl.glColor3f(1f,0f,0f);
        //THE RECTANGLE
        
    }

    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        
        
    }
}
```

`

After Compiling the above class I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/jone/IdeaProjects/final2/natives/macosx-universal/gluegen-rt
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2387)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:624)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:63)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:106)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:487)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:421)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:317)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:287)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:147)
    at Chap2_App_1.main(Chap2_App_1.java:58)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach to tackle this problem is by creating a basic gradle project. Gradle for Java is kinda NPM for NodeJs. So if you want to follow my guide i suggest you to:

Step 1 - Install gradle

Step 2 - Create a **basic** gradle project

Step 3 - Declare the dependencies into `build.gradle` file

Step 4 - Inside your gradle project, create a folder `src/main/java`

Step 5 - Place your main class file `Chap2_App_1.java` under `src/main/java`

Step 6 - Run your project

##### Disclaimer

This guide wasn't made in a macos but it might work in every OS (that's why any feedback is important) and this guide is easier than it looks so it's suggested to read it patiently.

## Requirements

- Java 8+
- Homebrew

### Step 1 - Install gradle

- Open the terminal and then you can install it by using `homebrew`:

```
brew install gradle
```

### Step 2 -  Create a *basic* gradle project

- Create the folder of your project: (java-opengl, for example)

```
mkdir java-opengl
```

- Enter your created folder

```
cd java-opengl
```

- Inside `java-opengl` folder, type:

```
echo 'no' | gradle init --type basic --dsl groovy --project-name java-opengl
```

If you type gradle init only it will prompt a series of questions and `echo 'no'` result **is pipelined to serve as input** to the last prompt of gradle's init task.

###### Gradle init flags

`--type` flag defines the project type

`--dsl` defines the script language used in the build file

`--project-name` is self explanatory

After the build is complete you might get the resulting project structure:

[image: gradle project structure]

### Step 3 - Declare the dependencies into `build.gradle` file

Your `build.gradle` might be empty but with comments generated by the init task.

By the time of writing this answer the latest version o jogamp-jogl is `2.5.0`.

So the content of your `build.gradle` might be like bellow:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jogamp.org/deployment/maven/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt-main
    implementation 'org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt-main:2.5.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all-main
    implementation 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all-main:2.5.0'
}
```

#### **Don't forget to save the content above**

### Step 4 - Inside your gradle project, create a folder `src/main/java`

Because the project is set as a `java plugin` gradle automatically searches for any source code into the `src/main/java` folder and compiles a target with the same structure.

Now just type:

```
mkdir src/main/java
```

[image: creating the source files folder]

### Step 5 - Place your main class file `Chap2_App_1.java` under `src/main/java`

Finally, move the code you posted into the folder created in the previous step.

### Step 6 - Run your project

Run your program by typing:

```
./gradlew run
```

**Attention:** To run the previous command you might be inside your project's folder.

Happy coding!!

### References

[Gradle install](https://gradle.org/install/)

[Setting Jogl dependencies in build.gradle file](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Gradle)

[How to organize gradle projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:separate_language_source_files)